# Variable changing...another variable?

Tags: c#, variables, int, swap

enter code here`I have a variable called curPos that stores two ints.
I have a second variable prevPos that stores two ints.

So I have the following code

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", curPos[0], curPos[1]); // 1, 25
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", prevPos[0], prevPos[1]); // 1, 25
                    curPos[0]++;

Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", curPos[0], curPos[1]); // 2, 25
Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", prevPos[0], prevPos[1]); // 2, 25
```

how is this even possible and this is the exact code when I step line by line to the last line shown
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkPKm7xEhac&feature=youtu.be

Comment: How are `curPos` and `prevPos` created? They are referencing the same array.

Comment: @Lee public static int[] curPos = { 25, 25 };
        public static int[] prevPos = { 25, 25 };

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They might be two different variables but they are pointing to the same object.

A variable is a compile time construct that gives a name to a storage location. At runtime that storage location is what we generally refer to as an object.

if you say

```
var foo = int[]{0,1};
var bar = foo;
```

you have one array that you can access through two variables. It subsequently does not matter whether you do

```
foo[0]++;
```

or you type

```
bar[00]++;
```

the result is the same. The first integer in the array is incremented by one.

This holds true as long as the type of the variables is a reference type such as an array. If the type of the variables is a Value type such as int or Point then any assignment will create a copy

```
Point foo = new Point();
var bar = foo;
```

in this case bar and foo does not point to the same object

Answer (score 4):

Both variables are pointing at the same array.  My guess is at some point in your code you have something like:

```
prevPos = curPos
```

When what you really want is

```
prevPos[0] = curPos[0]
prevPos[1] = curPos[1]
```

Comment: just to show you what I mean I have uploaded a step by step walk trough of the code http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkPKm7xEhac&feature=youtu.be

Comment: you can also use the `Array.Copy` method